# django set cookie and delete cookie

Tags: django, cookies

I am setting a cookie in django without response. when user logs in i trigger an api to authenticate its data and then i am trying to save its user_id in cookie in a class and then in another class am trying to delete the cookie means user is logged out.

```
class APIloginView(View):

    def get(self):
        r = requests.post(url,parameters)
        if 'user_id' not in request.COOKIES:
            request.COOKIES['user_id']='2133212332'
        print(request.COOKIES.get('user_id'))
    return HttpResponse(r)
```

but  when i try to access in value in another class it is showing me none

```
class logout(View):
    def get(self):
        print(request.COOKIES.get('user_id'))
        pass
```

Where am i doing wrong?and i know deleting a session like `del request.session['user_id']`,how to delete a particular cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookie needs to be set on response you are returning.

```
def get(self, request):
    r = requests.post(url,parameters)
    response = HttpResponse(r)
    response.set_cookie('user_id', '2133212332')
    return response
```

---

Also how come your code is even working. You are trying to access `request` everywhere, but it doesn't exists, because your `get` has no `request` parameter. What you mean to do is:

```
def get(self, request):
    ...
```